# Importing SQL file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a SQL file to fetch the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect('abc.sql')

tab = pd.read_sql_query("select * from user_tables",conn)
```

When I try to do so I am getting error. Error That I am getting is:

```
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'technical.sql' (11004)")
```

Comment: Can you include the content of `abc.sql` in the question?

Comment: abc.sql is a file that I downloaded from somewhere

Comment: but you still have to show it, because we have no clue what's inside and clearly that's what is throwing the error

Comment: You have not provided the host name, user name and password in connect(). That's causing the issue I believe.